# Custom site search by category

Tags: mysql

I want to create a simple search for a site that I'm working on. I have items in my db that all hold a specific category id and can optionally be linked to multiple tags.

I would like to take whatever search terms come in and query the category.name and tag.name fields to find the items that match those terms.

I'm looking for advice on how to create an efficient/quick query that does this AND orders the results by the items that match closest(most matches)

Here's a quick version of my relevant tables:

**item**

id | category | title | description

**category**

id | name | parentId

**tag**

id | name | uses

**item_tag**

itemId | tagId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still didn't entirely understand what you want.
Well, here's a first version for us to discuss.
I suggest you to create a view as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `search_view` AS
SELECT
  i.id    AS `item_id`,
  i.title AS `item_title`,
  c.id    AS `cat_id`,
  c.name  AS `cat_name`,
  t.id    AS `tag_id`,
  t.name  AS `tag_name`
FROM item AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_tag AS it
  ON (i.id = it.itemId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag AS t
  ON (it.tagId = t.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN category AS c
  ON (i.category = c.id)
WHERE ((t.id IS NOT NULL) OR (c.id IS NOT NULL));
```

And then you query from the view using something near

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    IF(tag_name like ?, 2, 0)
    + IF(cat_name like ?, 4, 0)
    + IF(item_title like ?, 1, 0)
  ) AS `priority`
  FROM search_view
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY SUM(priority);
```

*No tests in the code above. Report any problems you have*

**[first edition]** You use PHP, don't you?
Well, you can normalize your queries using [PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php); one way is to replace every occurrence of ',' by '|', remove extra spaces and perform the following query: *[I'll give an example using @VAR (actually you'll replace it with your input string)]*

```
SET @VAR = 'notebook|samsung';
SELECT
  *,
  (
    IF (tag_name REGEXP CONCAT('.*(', @VAR, ').*'), 2, 0)
    + IF (cat_name REGEXP CONCAT('.*(', @VAR, ').*'), 4, 0)
    + IF (item_title REGEXP CONCAT('.*(', @VAR, ').*'), 1, 0)
  ) AS `priority`
  FROM search_view
ORDER BY priority DESC;
```

This time I tested. Yes, you can use MySQL functions, something about `REPLACE(REPLACE(@VAR,' ',''), ',', '|')`. But I recommend you to do it in PHP (or java, python etc).

Comment: I haven't really worked with views. Is the above portion something that needs to be ran before each query or just once when the connection is created?

Comment: I really like your solution and the fact that you added search for the titles and gave weights to the different fields. If you have a chance would you be willing to explain how I might modify this to work with multiple search terms? They would be coming in as a comma delimited string.

Comment: @Helto, you create views just once, and then you query from them as if they were common tables (!). If you ever need to update your view, just run:
`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <view_name> AS <select...>`.

About your last doubt, I'll try to help you when I have time (today if possible) (let's see if I can)

Comment: Done! See if it works and mail me if you want {ER diagram, SQL script and a trigger I've made [Why did I make a trigger? For tag.uses column (just for fun)]}

Comment: Wow thanks, I will try this out as soon as I can. Yes I'm using php/PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.*
FROM items
LEFT JOIN categories
       ON categories.name = '< input name >'
      AND categories.id = items.category
LEFT JOIN item_tags
      AND item_tags.itemId = items.id
LEFT JOIN tags
       ON tags.name = '< input name >'
      AND tags.id = item_tags.tagId
WHERE categories.id IS NOT NULL
   OR tags.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY COUNT(items.id) DESC;
```

This may not be the fastest way. Basically you'll left join categories and tags to items while  making sure the category and tag have the correct name.  Filter out all items that don't match a category or an item_tag in the where clause.

Another alternative would be to create temporary tables.  Create one for all categories with the correct name, and one with all tags with the correct name. You could then SELECT items WHERE items.id IN categories_table OR items.id IN tags_table

Comment: I think this will get me on the right track, but table item_tag only maps tags to items, so the tag table needs to be joined in as well to search the name